# Is it the case that every UFD is noetherian on principal ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Its not the case that every UFD is noetherian; the standard counterexample is $R[x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots]$, which has the following ascending sequence of ideals:

$$\langle \rangle,\langle x_0\rangle,\langle x_0,x_1\rangle,\langle x_0,x_1,x_2\rangle,\ldots$$

But notice that most of these ideals aren't principal. So:

> **Question.** Is it the case that every UFD is noetherian on *principal* ideals?

Comment: Yes, in fact "An integral domain $R$ is a UFD if and only if it satisfies ascending chain condition on principal ideals (ACCP) and every irreducible is prime."

Comment: Yes. An integral domain is a UFD if and only if (1) principal ideals satisfy the ascending chain condition and (2) irreducible elements are prime. Basically (1) ensures the existence, (2) yields the uniqueness of factorizations.

Comment: $(b)\supsetneq (a)\Rightarrow b\mid a\,$ *properly* $\Rightarrow \nu(b) < \nu(a),\,$ for $\,\nu(n) = $ #prime factors of $\,n,\,$ e.g. $\nu(2^j 3^k) = j+k.\,$ So  an infinite properly ascending principal ideal chain yields an infinite properly descending sequence of naturals (the associated prime counts), contra $\Bbb N$ is well-ordered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes. Let $R$ be a UFD. Note that containment of two principal ideals $(a) \subset (b)$ corresponds with the division property $b \mid a$ for $a, b \in R$. Since $R$ is a UFD, every nonzero element has (up to multiplication by units) a unique finite factorization into irreducible elements, so let $a = x_{1}^{l_{1}}x_{2}^{l_{2}}\cdots x_{n}^{l_{n}}$ for irreducibles $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n} \in R$ and some integers $l_{1}, \ldots, l_{n} \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $(a) \subset (b)$ implies that $b$ is a product of some subset of $\{x_{1}, \ldots, x_{n}\}$ raised to appropriate powers. It is then clear that every chain of principal ideals must eventually stabilize, since the length of any such chain beginning with $(a)$ is bounded by $\prod_{i=1}^{n} l_{i}$.

Comment: Why don't you consider the cases where for instance,$a$ is a unit or zero?

Comment: If $a$ is a unit, then it generates the whole ring $R$, and so cannot be properly contained in any ideal of $R$. If we have a chain which begins with $a = 0$, then the next principal ideal in the chain must be generated by a nonzero element, in which case the analysis above applies.